# Show that $H= \cup _{r \in \mathbb {Q } \cap [0,1 ] }(K+r) $ is bounded, where $K $ is compact .

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $H= \cup _{r \in \mathbb {Q } \cap [0,1 ] }(K+r) $ is bounded, where $K + r $ denotes the translate and $K $ is compact .

This is sort of obvious but I want to construct an explicit example of a compact set that contains $H$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can claim it, but you could also try to prove it... (And that inclusion is false, in fact, try $K = \{0\}$)

Comment: Yes, thanks Najib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since $K$ is compact there's an $M > 0$ such that $K \subset [-M,M]$. now you can show that $H \subset [-M, M+1]$ - should be quite straightforward